# Pin an object on given coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, css

roughly said the purpose of my program is to place points or images on coordinates obtained from a click and over a div space. I face some difficulties with passing the x and y coords from the click to the point/image which actually to 'pin' it inside this  space where the script gets the mouse position. TO depict you, this is how it looks like, so far...

...

```
<style>
 #frames{
   width: 1280px;
   height: 720px;
   position: relative;
   border: 1px solid black;
  }

 #point{
    position:absolute;
    top:....; <-sth should be written here maybe?
    left:...; <-and sth here
  }
</style> 
....
<center><div id = "frames" onmousemove="coordinates(event)" onmouseout="clearcoords()" onclick="saveOO(event)">
<div id="point">
<img src="ball.png" heigth='30' width='30'>
</div>
```

```
  function saveOO(e){
  var savedOO;
   x = e.clientX;
   y = e.clientY;` 
   ...

    document.getElementById("point").style.top='x';
    document.getElementById("point").style.left='y';<-with those two lines I'm trying to pass x and y to the css #point characteristics, which apparently does not work for me so far

   }
```

For now it looks something like this and as well, x and y are global variables that's why I skipped them here...
Maybe I'm just messing sth. with the syntax, I'm not sure but if you have any ideas how to solve this I'll be glad to see your advice or answer and so on. And last but not at least, please try to avoid the use of JQuery.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting the position change your JavaScript to this instead:

```
  document.getElementById("point").style.top= y + 'px';
  document.getElementById("point").style.left= x + 'px';
```

You were nearly there, just missing the 'px' and you didn't need the single quotes around x and y.

By the way, you also have x and y mixed up, I think you wanted to set top to y and left to x.

Comment: Now, it's much better, thank you but here are the changes I've made so far. I edited as you adviced me to do both document.Element...()...s and then I changed position of #point form absolute to fixed. I still don't get well the difference between fixed, absolute and relative from w3 but I've to spend some more time on it, probably. There are some really minor adjustments which have to be done and then it should work flowlessly. A big, huge thank you! :D :D :D

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad that helped. I suggest learning the different options for position and trying them out. Here's a good article on the subject: https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/